# error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)"

Tags: c#, docker, cakebuild

I am trying to build the project inside docker by using build.ps1 and I get this error.

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319'.
Cake.exe : C:\Windows\TEMP\NuGetScratch\r21fikoo.0mb.nugetrestore.targets(452,20): error MSB4086: A numeric 
comparison was attempted on "$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition 
    "'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' < '15.0'".
```

But when I build in local computer shown like that:

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.6.0.22303' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

I am using this docker: `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Your Docker image doesn't have Visual Studio installed, hence a decent MSBuild version can't be located. If you need Visual Studio, it should be sufficient with the Visual Studio Built Tools. Take a look at the sample repository containing Dockerfiles for installing Visual Studio Build Tools here https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-dockerfiles.

Also read the announcement of the repository here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/docker-recipes-available-for-visual-studio-build-tools/.

Comment: I used this image and now ok  `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` . Thanks.