# NUGET restore: error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)" that evaluates to ""

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am getting the below error while running `nuget restore project.csproj`

`C:\Windows\TEMP\NuGetScratch\q43aqbtc.toq.nugetrestore.targets(459,20): error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' < '15.0'".`

I'm using MSBUILD version v4.8.3761.0  and .net framework from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788152/error-msb4086-a-numeric-comparison-was-attempted-on-msbuildassemblyversion)

Comment: I added a close vote: the reason is probably the same that is the cause for your issue. You have (or use) a very old MSBuild version, that doesn't have the [`MSBuildAssemblyVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022) reserved (predefined) property defined, thus it "evaluates" to "" which is not a number. Hence the warning. You need to use a "newer" version of MSBuild. You can install Visual Studio (Community Edition, or other depending on your needs/requirements).